# Display an image located in database Django 2.2

Tags: python, html, django, web-deployment

I want to get images from database to show on my html page but it is showing Page not found 404 http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/designs/myphoto.jpg

```
def index(request):

    topImgs = PortfolioImages.objects.filter(feature=2)
    botImgs = PortfolioImages.objects.filter(feature=3)

    return render(request, 'ideadunes/index.html', {'topImgs':topImgs, 'botImgs':botImgs})
```

Comment: please post your model code

Comment: add both code line in settings.py


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

Comment: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

Comment: Update your question instead of spamming in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your urls

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in template :

{{topImgs.url}}